# pyinstaller ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyinstaller

I have built a python script using tensorflow and I am now trying to convert it to an .exe file, but have ran into a problem. After using pyinstaller and running the program from the command prompt I get the following error:

```
File "site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 25, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.platform'
```

I have tried --hidden-import tensorflow.python.platform but it seems to have fixed nothing.
(The program runs just fine in the interpreter)
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write a hook: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to this stuff. I read the docs but didn't fully understand how to write the hook and how it differs from a hidden import. If you someone could guide me further that would be great.

Comment: I'll put an answer/tutorial on.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

EDIT: The latest versions of PyInstaller (4.0+) now include support for `tensorflow` out of the box.

Create a directory structure like this:

```
- main.py  # Your code goes here - don't bother actually naming you file this
- hooks
  - hook-tensorflow.py
```

Copy the following into `hook-tensorflow.py`:

```py
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all


def hook(hook_api):
    packages = [
        'tensorflow',
        'tensorflow_core',
        'astor'
    ]
    for package in packages:
        datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all(package)
        hook_api.add_datas(datas)
        hook_api.add_binaries(binaries)
        hook_api.add_imports(*hiddenimports)
```

Then, when compiling, add the command line option `--additional-hooks-dir=hooks`.

If you come across more not found errors, simply add the *full import name* into the `packages` list.

PS - for me, `main.py` was simply `from tensorflow import *`