# why shows ModuleNotFoundError after converting py to exe

Tags: python, module, notifications

[image]

I am beginner in python. So i can't understand the problem. i am using plyer for notification system. But it's not working after converting .py to .exe using auto-py-to-exe or pyinstaller. It's only working in IDE. I want get notification after opening .exe file.

Please help me to solve this.

```
from plyer import notification


def notifyMe(title, message):
    notification.notify(
        title=title,
        message=message,
        app_icon=None,
        timeout=15
    )

notifyMe("Hey Habib!", "Good Morning")
```

Comment: Two things. First, don't post images of error messages. Just copy and paste them into your post. Second, see if this helps you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60384288/pyinstaller-modulenotfounderror

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `--hidden-import plyer.platforms.win.notification` in the pyinstaller command For example : `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --hidden-import plyer.platforms.win.notification example.py`